# The usage of apostrophes - is the sentence "Save message file parameters to database" correct?

Tags: word-usage, apostrophe

A little confused - here is the sentence: `Save message file parameters to database`. Is it correct? Or should I add an apostrophe after `message` word?

Comment: I am also confused--why would you want an apostrophe there? To show possession? This construction  is sometimes called 'telegraph' , and is meant to be conserving of characters, i.e. conveying a succinct message.

Comment: "Message file" is a thing.  It's a file containing messages.

Comment: Why would you use an apostrophe? What meaning would that give?

Comment: The question "whose file?" makes me want to add an apostrophe like "message' file".. To change the word "message" to possessive. Maybe I'm wrong..

Answer (score 1):

The statement `Save message file parameters to database` sounds like some sort of button option to save a message file. In this context, the grammar rules are different; no apostrophe is needed.

Comment: If you can support this _opinion_ (per site standards) , I will upvote it.

Comment: This sounds like an option in a program, so no apostrophe is needed. If it has some other use I can't think of, perhaps it needs an apostrophe.

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear, so I just made an educated guess based on the information given.

Comment: Whoops, I don't have enough reputation. If I did, I would have done that.

Comment: The sentence is not a "button", but a comment near the source code.

Comment: As a comment in code it would certainly be understood, that is *whose* file or *whose* parameters. Anyone finding it will have gone through many pages of similar commands and references.

Comment: It sure does sound like something that would go in a messaging app or something. This would mean no apostrophe is needed.